# Node.js mailgun inline/embed images

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mailgun

How do you embed images with Node.js mailgun.
From reading the documentation, they use

```
-F inline=@files/cartman.jpg
```

The problem though, its for a curl example.

Here's what I have so far

```
Mailgun.sendHtmlEmail({
    apiKey: '..',
    domain: '...',
    toEmail: created.email,
    toName: created.email,
    subject: 'mySite update',
    htmlMessage: '<html><img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:test.png" width="600" height="64" /></html>',
    inline: 'email1/test.png',
    fromEmail: 'admin@mySite.com',
    fromName: 'Admin'
}).exec({
    // An unexpected error occurred.
    error: function (err){
        console.log(err);
    },
    // OK.
    success: function (){
    }
});
```

When this was tested, there was no image attached.

I'm assuming you have to access the inline file for the email in a way Node.js can understand.

If so how do you do that?

Can someone point me in the right direction, please.

Comment: If it helps, you generally should avoid inlining images in email. Sendgrid has a great resource on the topic here: [https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [mailcomposer](https://github.com/andris9/mailcomposer) module to generate email message with attachments.

```
mailcomposer = new MailComposer({forceEmbeddedImages: true});
mailcomposer.addAttachment({
  fileName: 'image.png',
  filePath: IMAGES_PATH + '/image.png',
  cid: '0o1q9i2w8u38ur.image.png'
});

mailcomposer.setMessageOption({
  to: created.email,
  from: 'admin@mySite.com',
  subject: 'mySite update',
  body: '...',
  html: '<html>...</html>'
});
```

And you can send it through mailgun:

```
mailcomposer.buildMessage(function (err, message) {
  if (err) {
    // ...
  }

  mailgun
    .messages()
    .sendMime({
      to: created.email,
      message: message
    }, function (err, response) {
      // ...
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am currently looking into nodemailer and using a gmail account to send emails.
I will also try this approach as well.

Comment: Just to clarify: the mailgun api shown in this answer is from [bojand/mailgun-js](https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js).